# Why the validation in Laravel not working properly?

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5, version

I am working in laravel version 5 and I have a form that gets the title and body of the question from the users. But while I press submit button the error message displayed said " The title field is required." But actually, I already type the title in the field.
This is a code in the controller page where I validate the felid and add them in my SQL DB.

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{
  $request->validate([
    'title'=>'required|max:50',
    'field'=>'required',
    'body'=>'required|max:50'
        
  ]);
  $title=$request->title;
  $field=$request->field;
  $body=$request->body;

  $projects =new Project;
  $projects->title=$title;
  $projects->body=$body;
  $projects->file=$field;
  $projects->user_id=auth()->user_id;

  $projects->save();
  return view('/welcome')->with('success','Question Added');

}
```

My Form Code is :

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="continer-fluid">
       {!! Form::open(['action'=>'App\Http\Controllers\QuestionController@store','method'=>'POST']) !!}
        {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="form-group">
                {{Form::label('titel','Titel')}}
                {{Form::text('titel','',['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Your Question Title'])}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{Form::label('field','Select your quetion filed')}}
                {{Form::select('field',['code'=>'Arduino Coding','hardware'=>'Hardwaer','IoT'=>'Internet of things']
                ,'',['class'=>'form-control','placeholder' => 'select a Field...'])}}
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                {{Form::label('body','Body')}}
                {{Form::textarea('body','',['name'=>'editor1','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Body text'])}}
            </div>
            {{Form::submit('Submit',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
 </div>
 @endsection
```

Comment: What does your form look like, can you post that code?

Comment: can you post the code of your form !?

Comment: Your input element is named `titel`, not `title`

Comment: @brombeer thanks, but what about the body field it had the same problem

Comment: Looks like `'name'=>'editor1'` in your body element overwrites the name. Take a look at the source/inspect the element to see which `name` attribute it has

Comment: @brombeer it has name editor1 , but actually this name I use it to mention  ckeditor  tool

Comment: Then change your validation field from `body` to `editor1`, if that's the `name` of the element

Comment: change this syntax according to documentation laravel `$this->validate($request, [` instead of this `$request->validate([`.

Answer (score -1):

it's a simple mistake in your form code change "titel" to "title"

so the new title input field,

```php
{{Form::text('title','',['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Your Question Title'])}}
```